# systemd script for starting my app server - Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, upstart

I have a upstart configuration file as shown below which works fine in Ubuntu 14:

```
#/etc/init/data_server.conf
#sudo start data_server
#sudo stop data_server
#sudo status data_server

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /opt/hold/data_server
respawn

post-start script
    echo "data server started at `date +"%F %T"` on `hostname -f`" | mailx -r "abc@host.com" -s "data server Started" "pqr@host.com"
end script

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

limit core unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 100000 100000
setuid goldy
exec ./proc_server --init_file=../config/tree.init --port=8080 --dir=/data/hold/ --max_sec=2400 --max_mb=100 --active=5
```

Now we are moving to Ubuntu 16 so we can't use `upstart` and looks like we need to use `systemd` here. I have to make sure whenever system is rebooted or app is killed it should start my `systemd` script automatically which in turn start my `data server`. So I came up with below `systemd` script: Let me know if this is the right way as I am doing it for the first time?

```
[Unit]
Description=test server
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
User=goldy
Group=goldy
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/hold/data_server
ExecStart=/opt/hold/data_server/proc_server --init_file=../config/tree.init --port=8080 --dir=/data/hold/ --max_sec=2400 --max_mb=100 --active=5
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
LimitNOFILE=100000
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Whenever I run above script, it gives me this error, I am not sure whats wrong?

```
[/lib/systemd/system/queue_server_two.service:3] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
```

Answer (score 22):

You are likely comparing `systemd` docs you've read online for a different version instead using the docs on your system that match your version.

Check `man systemd.unit` on your own system. You may find that on your version, the directive is named

`StartLimitInterval=` and should be used `[Service]`, not `[Unit]`.

I found the answer by searching for [systemd StartLimitIntervalSec](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-July/039255.html).

Comment: make sense thanks.. also is there any way I can add emailing thing in my `systemd` script just like I have in `upstart`?

Comment: @user1950349 [`ExecStartPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=)

Comment: systemd syntax doesn't support pipes, so you'll need something like `ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c ''`. Then you can put your command back in there as a quoted bash string. As seen in `man systemd.unit`, you can use %H for the host name, avoiding the call to `hostname -f`.

Comment: got it.. so that means this below line should work?

Comment: ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'echo "data server started at `date +"%F %T"` on %H" | mailx -r "abc@host.com" -s "data server Started" "pqr@host.com"'

Comment: Wow i've been searching all over trying to figure out this error. It appears in so many place, every web page I saw other than this says StartLimitIntervalSec is in Unit, not Service. I've been chasing a red herring because some places say it's StartLimitInterval not StartLimitIntervalSec. I'm using Centos 7.5.1804 (in a docker container, so man pages not easy), not some ancient OS. It's no wonder systemd gets a lot of flack. (but nope, still getting error)

Comment: @jamshid `man systemd.directives` will tell you where any any directive is documented. ` StartLimitIntervalSec=` goes in `Unit`. The above question is about `StartLimitInterval=`. By using your local man pages, you can be sure you are checking the docs for the version you are actually running.